# htaccess rewrite jpg files directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My video thumbs located /thumbs folder. But I want to serve thumbs like this: 
`http://example.com/f1b294327-1.jpg`

But currently serving this type:

`http://example.com/thumbs/f1b294327-1.jpg`

I tried this code:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)-(.*).jpg$ thumbs/$1-$2.jpg [QSA,L]
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code you tried? Looks fine to me.

Comment: internal server error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the groupings to:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)-([^/]+).jpg$ thumbs/$1-$2.jpg [QSA,L]
```